# setting selected menu item in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, menu, highlight

I am trying to highlight a chosen menu item that links to a new page. Swapping the background image to a lighter one works, but the setting is lagging behind on the pages. The index page is correct, but then it starts to highlight the previously clicked menu item.

I started using session attributes of JSP (`request.setAttribute("menuitem","home")`) on every page. The pages are comprised of 2 parts:

- header
- body

The menu is in the **header** and the whole page reloads on click of a menu item. Adding `setAttribute` happens via a scriptlet in the top of the body of each page. After the page is finished loading, I change the class to highlighted.

How can I solve this late response to highlighting change? ? Or should I use a different method?
**A menu item example:**

```
<div id="home" class="menu clickable" 
    <div>Home</div> 
</div>
```

**The script:**

```
<script>
    function checkMenuItem() {
        /*var selected=getMenuItem("selectedmenu");*/
        var selected = <%= (String) request.getAttribute("selectedmenu") %>
        if (selected != null && selected != "") {
            switch (selected) {
            case 'home':
                $("#home").removeClass('clickable').addClass('selected');
                $(".menu").not("#home").addClass('clickable'); <% chosenpage = "home";
                request.setAttribute("selectedmenu", chosenpage); %>
                break;
            case 'upload':
                $("#upload").removeClass('clickable').addClass('selected');
                $(".menu").not("#upload").addClass('clickable'); <% chosenpage = "upload";
                request.setAttribute("selectedmenu", chosenpage); %>
                break;
            case 'question':
                $("#question").removeClass('clickable').addClass('selected');
                $(".menu").not("#question").addClass('clickable'); <% chosenpage = "question";
                request.setAttribute("selectedmenu", chosenpage); %>
                break;
            case 'plan':
                $("#plan").removeClass('clickable').addClass('selected');
                $(".menu").not("#plan").addClass('clickable'); <% chosenpage = "plan";
                request.setAttribute("selectedmenu", chosenpage); %>
                break;
            case 'indication':
                $("#indication").removeClass('clickable').addClass('selected');
                $(".menu").not("#indication").addClass('clickable'); <% chosenpage = "indication";
                request.setAttribute("selectedmenu", chosenpage); %>
                break;
            default: $("#home").removeClass('clickable').addClass('selected');
              $(".menu").not("#home").addClass('clickable');
             break;
           }
        } //end if
    }



    $('document').ready(function () {
     checkMenuItem();    
         $("#home").click(
                 function(){ document.location.href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.html";} );
         $("#upload").click(
                 function(){ document.location.href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/upload.html";} );
         $("#indicator").click(
                 function(){ document.location.href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/plan/indicator.html";} );
         $("#plan").click(
                 function(){ document.location.href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/plan/improvementplans.html";} );
         $("#question").click(
                 function(){ document.location.href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/question.html";} );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So, you want to highlight the page you're currently at?

Comment: Does changing to a new page reload the head and footer too, or just the body? And if just the body are you using Ajax or an iframe, or...? It might be easier to give a sensible answer if you show (a cut-down version of) your markup and JS.

Comment: @Aadaam yes, exactly. I want to highlight that tab.

Comment: @nnnnnn a snippet `code`<div id="home" class="menu clickable"
onclick="document.location.href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.html'">
<div>Home</div>
</div>`code` I assume at least that this means only the body is changing. In any case, the header loads before the body. Sorry, the code formatting is not working well. I am new.

Comment: @BronWater Can you edit your question instead of pasting the code in the comment. It would have more visibility for others as well to answer your question more easily. Thanks

Comment: @PrakashK I updated it. There is a strange jumbled preview first. not sure why.